# How to output json object returned from REST api in powershell?

Tags: json, http, rest, powershell

I am trying to output to console a json object that is being returned when I call the URL:

```
http://localhost:999/api/randomObjects/19
```

where randomObjects is the type of object and 19 is the object ID. So far, the only way I have gotten the json to output to the console in powershell is using webclient and saving the json to a folder then outputting it.

```
$storageDir = "C:\Path\to\folder"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = "http://localhost:999/api/randomObjects/19"
$file = "$storageDir/demofile.json"
$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)
cat $file
```

Is there a way to directly output the json object to console without saving it in a file?

Answer (score 3):

There sure is: See the `ConvertTo-Json` and `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlets. These will transform to and from the JavaScript Object Notation textual format into a custom `PSObject` that you can query and manipulate using the regular tricks of the trade.

Comment: The prodigal son returns.  ;-)

Comment: Hah... yes, I know I've been absent for a few months now. It's also hard to beat MVP buggers like you to the punch :D

Comment: Thanks, this worked out great. For some reason it won't let me mark your answer as correct? Keeps saying "an error has occurred". I'll try again in a bit.

Comment: @SKLAK: You should now be able to mark this answer as the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a more direct method; if the API returns a JSON then it will convert to a PSObject if possible*.

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost:999/api/randomObjects/19
```

*if possible means "as long as the JSON isn't too big". See also:

- [Invoke-RestMethod doesn't create PS object out of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948989/invoke-restmethod-doesnt-create-ps-object-out-of-json)