# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod incomplete response

Tags: json, rest, http, powershell

Using PowerShell 5, I'm downloading from a REST endpoint by doing:

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "http://example.com/endpoint/item"
```

The result is 4Mb+ in size aprox. And sometimes `$result` is not a `PSObject` as I expect, but a string, which contains an incomplete JSON response.

So somehow I suspect there is a timeout, or something going on. But if that is the thing, then i tried using the `TimeoutSec` parameter with a very large number, like this:

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "http://example.com/endpoint/item" -TimeoutSec 10000
```

I had no luck: the response is broken (missing part on the JSON string).

Anyway, if there is a timeout involved, should'nt it throw an error?

Also, may be the problem is not on client side, but server side? I'm confused on which side is responsible here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConvertFrom-Json max length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854057/convertfrom-json-max-length)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you only get a PSObject from `Invoke-RestMethod` if it is able to convert the JSON string successfully. For a 4MB response this probably won't work. You can check this yourself by passing the the string through `ConvertFrom-Json` which will likely throw an error.

Similar questions were answered recently here:

- [Invoke-RestMethod doesn't create PS object out of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948989/invoke-restmethod-doesnt-create-ps-object-out-of-json)
- [ConvertFrom-Json max length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854057/convertfrom-json-max-length)

In short, you need to create a JavaScriptSerializer and set the MaxJsonLength appropriately.